# Save data in a variable instead of saving it in a hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, save

For now I am saving my returned data in a hidden input-field:

```
function(data) {
$("#input-hidden-field").text(data.error ? data.error : "");
}, "json");
```

I just wanted to ask you how to save the data in a variable instead of hidden input field?

UPDATE:

I want to save a string, which is returned from a script via json, in a variable and output this variable in a speechbubble:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#username-field").keyup(function(event) {
        $.post("checkUsername.php", {
            username: $(this).val()
        }, 
        function(data) {
            var string = text(data.error ? data.error : "");
        }, "json");

            $(this).qtip({
                overwrite: false,
                content: string,
                position: {
                    my: 'right center',
                    at: 'left center',
                    target: $(this),
                    viewport: $('#username-field')
                },
                show: {
                    event: event.type,
                    ready: true
                },
                hide: {
                    fixed: true
                }
            }, event); 
    });
});

<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username..." id="username-field" maxlength="20">
```

But this is not working; can anyone help me? No speechbubble appearing.

Comment: It looks like your qtip call is outside of your success function, so it doesn't have access to the `string` variable you define there. If you move the whole `$(this).qtip(...)` call into the function above it, does it work how you expect?